# Android NDK Build FFMPEG in 2021

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I'm working on an android app, and I have to convert `webm` files to `mp3`.
I really want to make a custom ffmpeg build, because it reduces the ffmpeg executable size to only 2MB.

My library **works** absolutely fine **when running on my PC**, but i'm struggling to build it for android... It seems like NDK architecture has changed and tutorials are outdated, and I can't find a proper and recent guide for android compiling...

I also would like to target all architectures (`aarch64`, `armv7`, `i686`, and `x86_64`)...

I've been on this for hours, fixed many errors, but still nothing has worked ><.
Please help me ! :\

PS. I'm compiling on Linux, here is my configuration script:

```
#!/bin/bash

API=31 # target android api

OUTPUT=/home/romain/dev/android/ffmpeg_build

NDK=/home/romain/android-sdk/ndk/23.0.7599858
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
SYSROOT=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot

TOOL_PREFIX="$TOOLCHAIN/bin/aarch64-linux-android"

CC="$TOOL_PREFIX$API-clang"
CXX="$TOOL_PREFIX$API-clang++"

./configure \
    --prefix=$OUTPUT \
    --target-os=android \
    --arch=$ARCH \
    --cpu=$CPU \
    --disable-everything \
    --disable-everything \
    --disable-network \
    --disable-autodetect \
    --enable-small \
    --enable-decoder=opus,vorbis \
    --enable-demuxer=matroska \
    --enable-muxer=mp3 \
    --enable-protocol=file \
    --enable-filter=aresample \
    --enable-libshine \
    --enable-encoder=libshine \
    --cc=$CC \
    --cxx=$CXX \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-0s -fpic"

make
make install
```

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg – this repo does all hard work for you, tune your parameters and run a simple script to get all architectures you care to support.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix should point to `$SYSROOT/usr/` and you misunderstood what `--prefix` mean. Its not output directory. Other than that i think nothing problematic than that (if it still happen please provide `ffbuild/config.log`)

Answer (score 0):

The repository pointed to by the previous answer is no longer being maintained.
[Here](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit) is an updated one.

This is the android branch: https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/android